# Access AWS from bash by IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ip

Do anyone possibly know how to access AWS having only server IP (239.255.255.255 for example) and .pem file from bash console in Ubuntu?

Comment: you mean, you want to ssh to an AWS EC2 instance, or you want to add your ssh key to authorized hosts, or you need your IP in the security groups? Your question is vague.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to SSH to the server, just use:

```
ssh -i yourkey.pem user@your.ip.addr.ess
```

user is ubuntu for ubuntu AMI, ec2-user for Amazon Linux, admin for Debian, etc.